# Updating tkinter rectangle dimensions on button press

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want my rectangle progress bar to have its dimensions change when I press a button, specifically by increasing the length by 10. For `tk.Label` I could use a `textvariable`, but I don't know how to use something like that for rectangle coords.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def buttonUpdate(width):
    return width.get()+10

root = tk.Tk()

v=tk.IntVar()
v.set(10)

tk.Button(root, text="+10", command=lambda:v.set(buttonUpdate(v))).grid()
tk.Label(root, textvariable=v).grid()

canvas=tk.Canvas(width=140, height=42)
canvas.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=2)
canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,v.get(),10,)

root.mainloop()
```

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: How about using `ttk.Progressbar` which supports using `IntVar` as what you want.

Comment: @acw1668 This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`canvas.create_rectangle` does not support use of variable as you are hoping, but I would suggest to use the `trace` method of variable like this to achieve what you want.

```
def update_rectangle(canvas, r):
    new = canvas.coords(r)
    new[2] = new[2] + 10
    canvas.coords(r, *new)

r = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,v.get(),10)
v.trace("w", lambda a,b,c: update_rectangle(canvas, r))

root.mainloop()
```

You can read more about `trace` method [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm).